# How to Remove or Deactivate "Application Passwords" in WordPress

Tags: password, profiles

With version 5.6, I got this new weird "Application Passwords" under all user profiles. No idea what it is and what it does except for what it says -- and I want it gone.

If anyone knows how to remove this using `__return_false` with a filter or something, please tell me. I've googled and looked at the developers handbook and so far; nothing.

See image for more information.[image: Application Passwords]

Comment: I guess you care more about removing the UI to avoid confusing your users? Or did you want to disable most of the REST API instead?

Comment: Both. Remove (de-activate) the Applicaion Passwords and as much as possible of the REST API without breaking basic functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's [wp_is_application_passwords_available](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_is_application_passwords_available/) to globally disable them:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_is_application_passwords_available', '__return_false' );
```

or [wp_is_application_passwords_available_for_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_is_application_passwords_available_for_user/) to turn them on and off by role or individually.

Comment: that worked just fine. thanks!